# When did Occam's razor historically become a common methodological precept?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, occams-razor

When I went to college, more than 30 years ago, as far as I can remember, nobody was talking about the use of Occam's razor in science. Reading the works of past scientists such as Einstein, Schrödinger, Heisenberg, just to mention some, I never see them invoking principles of parsimony, let alone cite Occam's razor. Nowadays, however, most consider it a cornerstone of science or a fundamental methodological rule that everyone is supposed to apply as if this were the case since the times of the inception of science. While it is a principle that dates back to William Occam in the 12th century, I'm wondering if it has been taken seriously only in the very recent history of science? Or did I miss something in my 1980s? Has anyone an idea when it became so famous?

Comment: At least as recently as 1937 when Occam's razor was used to deny the existence of absolute time: [Science and the Unobservable](https://www.nature.com/articles/140963b0) - "*the followers of Einstein maintained that if the physical world were regarded as including entities or conceptions which were Unobservable either directly or indirectly, there was no criterion for distinguishing the real from the unreal.*"

Comment: The more cranks there are, the more pushback there is. Crankery is about claims that make little sense, usually not containing outright inconsistent statements but with convoluted 'explanations'. Since there is no absolutely sure method to rule out consistent crankery, one must use simplicity to make a clear distinction. But even scientists mostly do **not** use Occam's razor correctly. See [this Math SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1736327/21820) for one rigorous way that can be proven to be optimal up to an additive constant.

Comment: Einstein said: “It can scarcely be denied that the supreme goal of all theory is to make the irreducible basic elements as simple and as few as possible without having to surrender the adequate representation of a single datum of experience.” Sometimes called Einstein's Blade, & paraphrased 'Things should be as simple as possible, but not simpler. He also said “To punish me for my contempt of authority, Fate has made me an authority myself.”

Comment: Per the Royal Society's maxim *Nullius in Verba* (Latin for "take nobody's word for it") can you cite specific words supporting your claim about contemporary science that "most consider it a cornerstone of science or a fundamental methodological rule that everyone is supposed to apply"?...

Comment: Would this (reworked) question be a good fit on [SE Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions)?

Comment: I can imagine that some debating string theory might more inclined to use Occam's razor (and the like) because experiments insofar cannot prove or disprove stuff like string theory, but without more (concrete evidence of the) context in which you say you see this surge in use this can't really be answered... and even then I suspect it's not a philosophical question proper.

Comment: In fact, I don't have to imagine it too much https://www.dummies.com/article/academics-the-arts/science/physics/string-theory-objectivity-and-the-rule-of-simplicity-177831/ There's a [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) stack where this would be more suitable. I'm inclined to suspect that you're overgeneralizing on its "revival" outside of narrow fields like that (like discussions about string theory).

Answer (score 4):

The kernel idea of Ockham's razor as a choice heuristic has been recorded long before Ockham's dictum. In *Physics* (Book 1, Chapter 6), Aristotle says that

> Since, then, one antithesis will suffice, it is better not to go
> beyond it; for the more limited, if adequate, is always preferable, as
> we saw in the case of Empedocles, who claims to get everything out of
> his four substances that Anaxagoras claims to get out of his unlimited
> number.

A continuation of the idea reads in Book 8 (Chapter 6)

> . . . for if the consequences are the same it is always better to
> assume the more limited antecedent . . .

It has been pointed out that, actually, William of Ockham's contemporary Durandus of Saint-Pourçain made much of this as a nominalist principle rather than Ockham himself did.

A main motivation for the Scholastic philosophers to espouse the principle was "to shave Plato's beard off with Ockham's razor", to say with an idiom coined by W. V. O. Quine in [*On What There Is*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20123117) as

> This is the old Platonic riddle of nonbeing. Nonbeing must in some
> sense be, otherwise what is it that there is not? This tangled
> doctrine might be nicknamed Plato's beard; historically it has proved
> tough, frequently dulling the edge of Occam's razor.

As an idiomatic term, it was coined by William Rowan Hamilton in the middle of the 19th century and entered general circulation. In his book *Discussions on Philosophy and Literature, Education and University Reform* (1861), Hamilton writes

> This is the law of parsimony; which prohibits, without a proven
> necessity, the multiplication of entities, powers, principles or
> causes; above all, the postulation of an unknown force where a known
> impotence can account for the phenomenon. We are, therefore, entitled
> to apply "Occam's razor" to this theory of causality, unless it be
> proved impossible to explain the causal judgment at a cheaper rate, by
> deriving it from a common, and that a negative, principle.

With the rise of experimental science, nominalism has come to be closely allied with empiricism. The line of thought roughly goes as: the reality consists of particular things, universal/general names only imply some similarity between those particular things, not an ontological existence of the beings they name. So, names are linguistic items not signifying any reality distinct from the particulars. Through our senses, we do not experience universals or general terms, but particular things. Our knowledge is basically derived from that experience. Hence, nominalist ontology and empiricist epistemology complete each other.

This line of thought was revived with the flourishing employment of methods based on logic, foundations of mathematics and linguistics in philosophy. As the most notable exponents of this revival, Quine and Nelson Goodman can be cited. Effectively, this style of philosophising has replaced the earlier logical positivism (an interesting trace of it can be observed in logic, the universal statements, such as 'all humans are mammals', are rendered as ∀*x*(H(*x*) → M(*x*)), i.e., 'for any *x*, if *x* is a human, then it is a mammal').

A secondary of reason is, partly a social one, that the principle of Ockham's razor has gained popularity as one of the basic tenets of philosophical rigour, to avoid ungrounded claims. A drawback of this stance, is that, while promoting sparse ontology against rich ontology, it may become prone to produce views shorn of explanatory power.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. 

However, as I said, even though the principle dates back to Aristotle and has been applied throughout the history of science and philosophy, I contend that, at least in physics, it had no or scarce relevance until very recently. Yes, Newton, Einstein, and others sometimes hinted at it, but overall, if one reads the treatises of scientists before the 1990s, the word "Occam" is almost nonexistent. My understanding is that it has become nowadays almost a fashion that we would like to present as an inherent principle of science. But that was not always the case.

Comment: The intention in my last paragraph is to address the part of your comment that falls into the lot of philosophy. Outside philosophy, one may find it a fancier way to talk against anything one thinks redundant. But it gets emptier, as it gets broader coverage.

Answer (score 2):

> Nowadays, however, most consider it a cornerstone of science or a fundamental methodological rule that everyone is supposed to apply as if this were the case since the times of the inception of science.

Occam's razor merely describes an existing way of applying common sense and finding consensus in rational debate. Nobody is "supposed to follow it", instead, people in all ages "have been observed to follow it". Not following it leads to plenty of competing theories which would all be regarded equally likely, hence do not help with finding consensus or deciding which one to presuppose going forward.

> I'm wondering if it has been taken seriously only in the very recent history of science?

As [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor): "In the scientific method, Occam's razor is **not** considered an irrefutable principle of logic or a scientific result;"

Whether and why it is mentioned more often recently than before seems a matter of opinion, and not a good question for this site.

Comment: The question is more of a historical character. If the principle is mentioned more often recently than before, is not a matter of opinion, but a fact of the history of science/philosophy, and as such would tell us something about the perception of scientists/philosophers in the times about science, reality, epistemology.

Comment: Some trends are just fashions, without deeper meaning.